# php json_encode not returning proper json encoded string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using a jquery ajax  call which accepts json response :

```
 var posturl = '/admin/getparamdetails/';
    var data = "adnetworkId="+adnetworkId;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: posturl,
        data : data,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(msg){
            //$("#displayPramForm").html(msg);
            //alert('hello'+msg.length+' '+msg.hello.length);
            console.log(msg);
            if(msg!='')
            {
                alert(msg.hello);
            }
        },
        failure: function(msg){}
    });
```

in my php backend function , I am using json_encode on a simple array as shown:

```
 $json_encoded_string =  json_encode(array("hello"=>'abc'));
 echo $json_encoded_string;
 die;
```

but **alert(msg.hello)** returns **undefined** for me. What is going wrong here ?
Also , in my **console.log** I am able to get the output as :

```
{"hello":"abc"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) on the return data:

```
if (msg) {
  msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
  alert(msg.hello);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to send the data as Content-Type "application/json", otherwise it won't work.

Just add the following in your PHP File:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: It should be ```header('Content-Type: application/json');```